# How to minify selected styles?

Tags: javascript, css, sublimetext3, minify

I've been using Sublime for more than 2 years, but now I've come to know the minification of CSS and JavaScript files as well. So I'm using [Minify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Minify) plugin, but this plugin only work in a separate .css .js file. But one might have styles in **style tag** as well. So how should I minify these styles?
Currently I'm using [minifier.org](https://www.minifier.org/) do this.

Answer (score 1):

This should not depend on your IDE but on your build system.

Comment: how it can depend on build system?

Comment: those tools in sublim text are gadgets, and you should use them in some case, but for a real project, look at grunt/gulp/webpack/rollup where you will have more granularity

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but actually i don't know about grunt/gulp/webpack/rollup. will check them as well if they can help me out :)